# Analytical evaluation of the following integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}\ln\left({1\over2}+{1\over2}\text{erf}\left\{{x\over\sqrt{2}}\right\}\right)H_n(x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}~dx$

Where $H_n$ are "probabilists' [Hermite polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials)".

Comment: The integral should be equal to $0$ as the lower limit and the upper limit are the same.

Comment: Hi, Harry yes your right. That was a typo. Good spot.

Comment: Mathematica couldn't even do the $n=0$ case - not that it's not doable, but it doesn't give me confidence for arbitrary values of $n$.

Comment: @RonGordon, my copy could, the result agreeing with GEdgar. I did some manipulation based on properties of Hermite polynomials and also didn't see much hope for $n>0$.

Answer (score 1):

I get (with the help of Maple)
$$
\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\!\ln  \left( 1/2+1/2\,
{{\rm erf}\left(1/2\,x\sqrt {2}\right)} \right) {{\rm e}^{-1/2\,{x}^{2
}}}{dx}=-\sqrt {2\pi }
$$
but not the case $n=1$.